# Django - cannot deploy with mod_wsgi in virtualenv with python 3.4

Tags: django, apache, python-3.x, mod-wsgi

i've been trying for two days and still can't deploy my django proj to apache + mod_wsgi-express in virtualenv with python3.4. I'm getting Internal Server Error on the web browser. please help~~~

**note: i am running mod_wsgi with operating system Apache 2.4.10**

in terminal, i ran mod_wsgi-express with the following command:

```
(env3.4)root@X110:/var/www/html/example.com/mysite# mod_wsgi-express start-server --host 192.168.1.110 --port 8000 --working-directory mysite --application-type module mysite.wsgi --user developer --group developer
Server URL         : http://192.168.1.110:8000/
Server Root        : /tmp/mod_wsgi-192.168.1.110:8000:0
Server Conf        : /tmp/mod_wsgi-192.168.1.110:8000:0/httpd.conf
Error Log File     : /tmp/mod_wsgi-192.168.1.110:8000:0/error_log (warn)
Request Capacity   : 5 (1 process * 5 threads)
Request Timeout    : 60 (seconds)
Startup Timeout    : 15 (seconds)
Queue Backlog      : 100 (connections)
Queue Timeout      : 45 (seconds)
Server Capacity    : 20 (event/worker), 20 (prefork)
Server Backlog     : 500 (connections)
Locale Setting     : C.UTF-8
```

error log:

```
[Thu Nov 10 01:05:11.682936 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 4692:tid 139781773657856] [remote 192.168.1.10:54805] mod_wsgi (pid=4692): Target WSGI script '/tmp/mod_wsgi-192.168.1.110:8000:0/handler.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Nov 10 01:05:11.683051 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 4692:tid 139781773657856] [remote 192.168.1.10:54805] mod_wsgi (pid=4692): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/tmp/mod_wsgi-192.168.1.110:8000:0/handler.wsgi'.
[Thu Nov 10 01:05:11.683109 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 4692:tid 139781773657856] [remote 192.168.1.10:54805] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Nov 10 01:05:11.683194 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 4692:tid 139781773657856] [remote 192.168.1.10:54805]   File "/tmp/mod_wsgi-192.168.1.110:8000:0/handler.wsgi", line 94, in <module>
[Thu Nov 10 01:05:11.683213 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 4692:tid 139781773657856] [remote 192.168.1.10:54805]     recorder_directory=recorder_directory)
[Thu Nov 10 01:05:11.683266 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 4692:tid 139781773657856] [remote 192.168.1.10:54805]   File "/var/www/html/example.com/env3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/__init__.py", line 1335, in __init__
[Thu Nov 10 01:05:11.683290 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 4692:tid 139781773657856] [remote 192.168.1.10:54805]     __import__(entry_point)
[Thu Nov 10 01:05:11.683323 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 4692:tid 139781773657856] [remote 192.168.1.10:54805] ImportError: No module named 'mysite'
```

============================================================

below are my settings.

operating system

```
os: debian 8.6.0
ip address: 192.168.1.110
apt-get install build-essential
apt-get install libssl-dev
apt-get install apache2-threaded-dev
apt-get install python-dev
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

created a virtualenv with python 3.4

```
virtualenv env3.4 --python=python3.4
```

in the virtualenv, i've installed the following with pip:

```
pip install django #django 1.10.3
pip install -U setuptools
pip install mysqlclient
pip install djangorestframework
pip install django-filter
pip install httpie
pip install coreapi (to include api schema)
pip install coreapi-cli (client)
pip install mod_wsgi
```

project structure:

```
/var/www/html/example.com/mysite
                           +mysite
                               settings.py
                               urls.py
                               wsgi.py
                           +app1
                           +app2
```

settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.1.110']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    .....
    'rest_framework',
    'mod_wsgi.server',
]
....
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: And if you take out ``--working-directory mysite``? May be of interest to also read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/04/using-modwsgi-express-with-django.html and http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/04/integrating-modwsgi-express-as-django.html

Comment: hi @Graham Dumpleton, that works. thank you very much